# How do I save a blender file as a MP4 in 2.80 video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I just started using 2.8 for video editing. I've rendered the video but it always saves as a blender file. And it makes it hard to put the videos on YouTube. Is there any way to save it as a MP4 file.

Answer (score 10):

The following configuration produces an .mp4 file with codecs that are recommended by the [YouTube guidelines](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4603579?hl=en) and their [recommended upload encoding](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en):

- Output format: *FFmpeg video*
- Container: *MPEG-4*
- Video codec: *H.264*
- Audio codec: *AAC*

Adjust the output path to where you want the video saved. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or use *Render > Render Animation* in the UI to save the video.

[image: Output configuration]