# How to get shading to show in different tabs?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

First time using Blender. I've followed a tutorial for creating a simple animation and I'd like to save it as a video or image sequence, but I'm not sure how to do this. My work shows in the "shading" tab, but not in any other tab.

What am I missing? Also, I was working on this in the animation tab yesterday and it was visible. Today, I can't see it there.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Everything is saved in your project, you're just in solid mode instead of the look dev mode for the *Viewport Shading*. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/shading.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/introduction.html#display-shading

Comment: For saving as video: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150388/how-do-i-save-a-blender-file-as-a-mp4-in-2-80-video-editing

Comment: Thanks! This helped.